# What is the argument of the split-complex number? Is it the hyperbolic angle of the number's vector?

Tags: logarithms, hypercomplex-numbers, split-complex-numbers

In split-complex numbers, what is the analog of argument of the complex numbers?

I think, it is $\arg(a+bj)=\frac12\log \left(\frac{a+b}{a-b}\right)$.

Comment: I *think* that makes sense; if you take a split-complex number $m$ with unit modulus, I think you get $\arg(m^k) = k\arg(m)$, right?

Comment: Although...would it make sense to multiply that by $1/2$, so as to align it with inverse hyperbolic tangent?

Comment: @BrianTung yes,yes. I agree!

Comment: @BrianTung so, the argument is $\log\sqrt{\frac{a+b}{a-b}}$ and modulus is $\sqrt{(a+b)(a-b)}=\sqrt{a^2-b^2}$, and the both can be imaginary (but in the conjugate quadrants)!

Comment: @BrianTung and $z=|z|e^{j\arg z}$.

Comment: @BrianTung by the way, the fact that in split numbers the modulus and the argument can be imaginary, clearly indicates that they are super-structure over complex numbers, and should be build after them. The combined structure will be tessarines.